# How to convert "\x1b" into a real control character "[Esc]"

Tags: python, command-line-arguments

I get a user written string as a command line parameter and have the problem that i literally get what the user writes, which results in the string "1\x1b2" to be 6 characters long, instead of the \x1b to be converted into an control character like i need it to be.

i searched for hours and did find nothing. every character encoding i tried failed (which is logical since it is not a control character).

is there another way than replacing the string "\x1b" by hand (regexp)?

Comment: I think you just have to know that `\x1b` is Escape.

Comment: *...which results in the string `"1\x1b2"` to be 6 characters long...* Are you sure about that? Can you verify that it is indeed the string which has 6 characters instead of it being just the representation?

Comment: Can you show us your code of how the argument is entered and you outputing the string with with a length of 6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It actually is an encoding known to [Python's codec library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#python-specific-encodings):

```
s = r"1\x1b2"
dec = s.decode('string_escape')
print len(dec), repr(dec)
```

But this might not be the exact context your escapes are written for.

Comment: Whoops. I use it indirectly; the first version dug down into `codecs.escape_decode`, but that import is not needed in this version.

Comment: While many languages use backslash escapes inherited from C, there may be subtle differences. For instance, some might not stop at two hexadecimal or three octal digits. The string_escape codec handles the escapes as Python would specifically.